# Ajax code to intercept a form submit not working with twitter

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter, google-chrome-extension, form-submit

I am working on a chrome-extension that intercepts a form submit event of a webpage and checks the headers. I am using jquery form intercept for the same. It's working for most sites, but off late I found it is not working for twitter. Has anyone experienced the same? I am not sure whether it is any change of API or some mistake on my code.Attached my form intercept code.

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  e.preventDefault();
  process(function() {
  $this.unbind('submit');
  $this.submit();
  });
}); 

process = function(callback) {
  alert("inside process");
  alert("location.href");
};
```

Thanks,
Shankar

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: I have an alert statement as soon as it inside the process function, but it is not entering the method call itself.

Comment: You need to post more code then.

Comment: Hi @Jack I have updated the code in the process function (dummy code just to make sure it retrieves fine) . Even this does not work.

Comment: Are you sure it executes up to `e.preventDefault()`? I'm guessing your `submit()` never gets called.

Comment: It worked for Gmail,Facebook,yahoo. So I assumed that should be method..:) Will probably check whether some other method works. Any help is also highly appreciated.

Comment: Could Twitter be using some other solution than actually submitting a form?

Comment: @DavidMårtensson Not too sure. It was working a month back. But if yes, it's actually a welcome change. I find rest of the social networks pretty easy to hack...

Comment: If they use a form but send the data using ajax you might never trigger the submit event on the form, and you might need to see if there is any twitter events you could hook into, or maybe listening to the get/post requests to intercept them.

Comment: sure @DavidMårtensson Will update if something works out.Thanks for your help. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just an update. It actually works for the sidebar login (provided in the screen shot below). But only in the regular login, its not working. Could be a security feature. But I found all password manager utilities to intercept the submit. Will update if I found the reason.

Thanks,
Shankar

[image: Login Page]